# how to prove uniqueness of the solution for a DE using Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

More specifically :- I have to prove that 
$f(x)= 1-\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$ is a unique solution on [-1,1] for the DE:
$y''=(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}, y(0)=1,y'(0)=1$

I am totally lost on this topic.
So far, I tried to proceed as saying:-
$g(y',(1+(y')^2)^{3/2})$ is a continuosly differentiable function and therefore Lipschitz on any compact set.
and $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at 0.
So maximize $||g(.)||_\infty $ in the neighborhood of (0,1) to find the radius in which this solution works using local Picard condition.

Am I even close to the right way to do this?

Comment: What are you allowed to assume? Do you know picard's theorem and are trying to prove that this function satisfies the hypotheses or are you starting from scratch?

Comment: @ I know the theorem and trying to prove it using that.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never done a problem like this and below is my take.

Note that a differentiable function is Lipschitz if and only if it has bounded derivative.

You then need to verify that the RHS of $y''=(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}=g(y')$ is Lipschitz. A change of variables, maybe taking $f=y'$ should convince you that modulo needing more initial conditions, this set up is exactly what Picard's theorem allows you to tackle.

So differentiating, we have
$$
g'(y')=3(1+(y')^2)^{1/2}2y'\leq 6(1+(1+\delta))*(1+\delta)=6(2+\delta)(1+\delta)
$$
and is thus locally Lipschitz around $y'(0)=1$, implying that a solution to the IVP is unique Verifying that what you have is in fact a solution involves differentiating a few times and plugging stuff in.